# xampp how to change url : mysite.localhost to www.mysite.com

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

Many thank you for read this Question

**first we add**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com
```

to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

**and file httpd-vhosts.conf add**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
 ServerName www.mysite.com
 ServerAlias mysite.com
 <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">

 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**and httpd.conf change**

```
DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
<Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">
```

we restart apache and type www.mysite.com
that look good site run but in url show mysite.localhost

how to change url to www.mysite.com Many thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and edit as `Administrator => hosts` file.

Add in end of file:

`127.0.0.1   www.mysite.com`

**Save and close.**

**Step 2**: Go to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` and edit `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Add in end of file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

**Save and close.**

**Final step…**

Restart **XAMPP**(Click **Stop** and after that **Start** in Apache section). Open in your browser `www.mysite.com`

Comment: Many thank you we do same you comment but when we type in url  www.mysite.com it show mysite.localhost

how to change url to www.mysite.com Many thank you

Comment: @woraeut at my side it work like a charm with this approach.